# Parsing string for DB entry

Tags: php

If I have the following code before inserting the value into my SQL database would it be deemed secure for a raw query insert?

```
myParse(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($body)))
```

`myParse` would be the following :

```
function myParse($string) {
     return ltrim(rtrim(nl2br($string)));
}
```

Comment: Hello.  I would suggest you use prepared statements to insert data from a user into your database.  In this way you will not have to worry about sanitizing the data on the way in.  This means you can access the user data in a variety of different ways as it hasn't been altered.  You will, however, want to sanitize the data before you inject it into a web page.  Run htmlspecialchars on it, or whatever else seems appropriate and safe.

Answer (score 0):

Your should use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) functions

Comment: Alternatively (and perhaps the better option), use prepared statements instead. Also, **don't use the `mysql_*` functions!**

Comment: @Bytewave Use or not use the mysql* - it depends on the system. There are thousends of systems on servers with php versions <= 5.4 where uses full mysql*. And they work quite well - in order to change something.

Comment: At this point if you're stuck below 5.4 it's probably time to find a new web host. `mysql_*` is deprecated and **removed** as of PHP 7 and should not be used in new projects wherever possible.

Comment: @Bytewave These are just words. In fact, you will do what your customers tell you. And if customers say that they are not going to update the version of PHP, then you will work on version 4.7-5.2.

Comment: Even on PHP 5.0, you have the option of out-of-date `mysqli`, which is still better than the `mysql` extension. Surely your customer would be interested in the security of the product you're building for them. If you find yourself in a situation where you're stuck in an archaic environment, yes, you work with what you have. But in most cases, whenever possible, you should use the updated extensions.